# В какой класс помещать конструктор SQLite?

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, sqlite, ionic

Задача - подключить SQLite к проекту. Имеется Конструктор. Он должен быть помещен в Класс.

Вопрос: в какой класс поместить конструктор?

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

'use strict';

class DataBase {

  constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) { }
   this.sqlite.create({
     name: 'data.db',
     location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

    db.executeSql('create table Newslist(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
      .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

  })
} 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Помещайте в тот класс, в котором хотите использовать объект `sqlite`

Comment: Создал класс DataBase. Поместил туда Конструктор. TS указывает (подчеркивает) на пресловутый 'this', называя его "неожиданным токеном". После закрывающей фигурной скобки тела конструктора Lint пишет: "ожидается объявление или оператор".

Comment: Вы полный файл DataBase приведите в вашем вопросе. `this.sqlite` можно будет использовать в методах класса или в конструкторе.

Comment: Что значит "полный файл DataBase"? app.module.ts  - внутрь этого модуля я поместил Класс и Конструктор. На всякий случай исправлю код, поместив туда все содержимое модуля app.module.ts .

Comment: стало быть, this.sqlite должен быть написан внутри фигурных скобок класса?

Comment: Вот так стало сразу гораздо понятнее! И ответ сразу же появился!)

Answer (score 2):

В коде имеется ошибка синтаксиса:

```
class DataBase {

  constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) { }
   this.sqlite.create({
     name: 'data.db',
     location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

    db.executeSql('create table Newslist(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
      .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

  })
}
```

В теле класса могут быть определения полей, конструктора, методов и свойств.

В данном случае идет попытка выполнить сразу код.

Для решения достаточно поместить этот код в тело метода, либо конструктора:

```
class DataBase {
    constructor(private sqlite: SQLite) {  // Начало конструктора
        this.sqlite.create({
            name: 'data.db',
            location: 'default'
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
            db.executeSql('create table Newslist(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
              .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
              .catch(e => console.log(e));
        });
    } // конец конструктора
}
```